# Patch panel problem

Tags: switch, patch-panel

We have a couple of ip cameras. The company who delivered those also made the UTP cables. They had them directly in the switch. I now changed it to go trough the patch pane, but i just can't get a few of them working. We use the T568B configuration. But after checking the utp cable at the camera i noticed that they made the utp cable like this:

brown - brown/white - green - blue/white - blue - green/white - orange - orange/white

**How do i put them in our patch panel?**

I tried to reverse(Brown in blue/white in the patch panel etc.) them (since they did the cable the wrong way), but with no succes. I tested it with our cable tester and the LEDs just went from 6 to 3 etc.
[image: Example]

Comment: community reminder: Physcial infrastructure is explicitly ON-topic, as per, ["Is phys infrastructure on topic?"](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/269/last-call-for-input-is-physical-infrastructure-on-topic?cb=1)

Comment: Are you certain all the patch panel runs are tested/good and actually wired back to a switch? Are you certain adding the patch panel into the mix isn't making one of the IP cameras' total run length too long?

Comment: That's T568B in reverse... did you look at this with the tab on the RJ45 connector facing away from you, or towards you?

Comment: I am certain that the patch panel is good and wired back to a switch. Lenght should not be a problem i took a few meters from all the cables. I made an RJ45 on them since they have to run tonight and they are working again. I know it is T568B in reverse and they did it only on the first floor. The second floor is just fine. I look always with the RJ45 tab away from me.

Comment: why not fix their wiring "errors". Redo the camera ends with your site's preferred wiring, and then punch them down at the patch panel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is you don't "fix" it at the patch panel.  If you follow the code and it doesn't work, you need to fix the other side.

One of the reasons people use T568A/B and not any straight through wiring pattern they want is that it makes troubleshooting and repairs much simpler, as you are finding out now.  If you don't fix the other end now, you will be in the same situation (or someone else will) 5 years from now while trying to fix the camera side of the cable.

I also firmly believe that infrastructure cabling should be infrastructure cabling, not a "long patch cord" running through a building.  So I would terminate the camera end of the cables to a jack and use a patch cable to connect the cameras.

If you *really must* take the shortcut (for instance, it is more important to get the camera up ASAP), then you can do so, but put this on your priority list of things to fix ASAP.  Just "reverse" where you punch down, since brown is where white/orange should be on the far end, punch it down where white/orange should be.  White/brown to orange, green to white/green, and white/blue to blue.

I also recommend that you develop a cable standards document detailing how you expect cabling to be run for your organization and provide it to any contractor working at your site.  Then enforce the document before you allow them to get paid.

Comment: I've added it to the list of what has to be done. This will probably not be done by me, But i am going to reccomend it to the system administrator. Probaby the next intern or himself will do it. I documented excactly how I have patched them so he will know what to do when there are any problems and he needs to repatch them.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

It really doesn't matter how the patch panel is wired (A vs. B) as long as it's the same at both ends. (i.e. "straight through") The same is true of the cable.

Unless your IP cameras have some Special Needs™ (eg. cisco pre-standard power, ubiquiti non-48V poe, etc.), there shouldn't be any need for hacked up cables. You haven't said exactly what hardware we're dealing with (switches and cameras)